# How to Calculate dates between a given rage?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, magento2.4, php-7

I want to calculate dates between current date and  given range
for example last 30 days date with the gap of 5 days
the array should be in this formate.

- **Formate:**
- **2022-8-18 00:00:00**
- **2022-8-13 00:00:00**
- **2022-8-8 00:00:00**
- **2022-8-3 00:00:00**

but instead i got array with times, always increseing,

[image]

**and this is my code**

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$period = [];
$dayNumber = 30;
$day = 5;


$to = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // current date

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $from = strtotime("-" . $day . " day", strtotime($to));
    $period[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $from);
    $day += 5;
    if ($day >= $dayNumber) {
        break;
    }

}

print_r($period);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your logic, but correct way in UTC is

```
$periods = [];
$from = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$from->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$to = clone $from;
$to->sub(new \DateInterval('P30D'));
while ($to < $from) {
    $periods[] = $from->format('Y-n-j H:i:s');
    $from->sub(new \DateInterval('P5D'));
}

var_dump($periods);
```

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "2022-8-18 00:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "2022-8-13 00:00:00"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "2022-8-8 00:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "2022-8-3 00:00:00"
  [4]=>
  string(18) "2022-7-29 00:00:00"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "2022-7-24 00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: how do you always knows the correct answers?

Comment: One more question:
can we use users input days in your logic, 
like the user should put total no of days can be 30,20 10 and the date gap should be user input too, can be 2,5 or 10 days gap

Comment: P30D and P5D can they be user input, like these values comming in parameters of a function

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. If you are operate dates you can use `sprintf('P%dD', $days)`. The format is [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Answer (score 0):

try removing time format from this code

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$period = [];
$dayNumber = 30;
$day = 5;


$to = date("Y-m-d"); // current date

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $from = strtotime("-" . $day . " day", strtotime($to));
    $period[] = date('Y-m-d', $from);
    $day += 5;
    if ($day >= $dayNumber) {
        break;
    }

}
print_r($period);
```

the resulted array will work like as you wanted
and this is equivalent to

- **2022-08-18 == 2022-08-18 00:00:00**

[image]